# How to make spinner background transparent in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Here is my spinner layout,

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerQuality"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```

and spinner item layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
```

and showing spinner is,
[image]

But i want to get both spinner and dropdown items background transparent.
How would i get that?

Answer (score 17):

Try this
//to change the dropdown background

```
android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

//to change the spinner background

```
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Its working for dropdown item layout but how to do for main spinner layout?

Comment: Is not this change hide down arrow sign (indicator) of spinner layout?

Answer (score 3):

Set:

```
android.popupBackground="@null"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

add style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_pastels</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue_pastels</item>
</style>
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

in java code add :

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List type = new ArrayList();
    type.add("12");
    type.add("13");
    type.add("14");
    type.add("11");
    ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_item, type );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

create res/layout/spinner_item.xml and add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@color/white_00" />
```

create res/layout/spinner_item_dropdown.xml and add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="12dip"
android:paddingEnd="7dip"
android:layout_margin="20dip"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:theme="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
android:textSize="14sp"

android:background="@color/TRANSPARENT"
android:backgroundTint="@color/theme_gray_10"
android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to  textview and see if it helps.

Comment: when i remove android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" its not showing down arrow. I also need to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<Spinner
 android:background="@null"
 android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: where i remove android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" its not showing down arrow. I also need to show this.